# open file with a unicode filename?

Tags: python, file, unicode

I don't seem to be able to open a file which has a unicode filename. Lets say I do:

```
for i in os.listdir():
    open(i, 'r')
```

When I try to search for some solution, I always get pages about how to read and write a unicode string to a file, not how to open a file with `file()` or `open()` which has a unicode name.

Comment: The code you have posted is how I would do it. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Yes, what about that code doesn't work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simply pass `open()` a unicode string for the file name:

In Python 2.x:

```
>>> open(u'someUnicodeFilenameλ')
<open file u'someUnicodeFilename\u03bb', mode 'r' at 0x7f1b97e70780>
```

In Python 3.x, all strings are Unicode, so there is literally nothing to it.

As always, note that the best way to open a file is always using the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) in conjunction with `open()`.

Edit: With regards to `os.listdir()` the advice again varies, under Python 2.x, you have to be careful:

> os.listdir(), which returns filenames, raises an issue: should it return the Unicode version of filenames, or should it return 8-bit strings containing the encoded versions? os.listdir() will do both, depending on whether you provided the directory path as an 8-bit string or a Unicode string. If you pass a Unicode string as the path, filenames will be decoded using the filesystem’s encoding and a list of Unicode strings will be returned, while passing an 8-bit path will return the 8-bit versions of the filenames.

[Source](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-filenames)

So in short, if you want Unicode out, put Unicode in:

```
>>> os.listdir(".")
['someUnicodeFilename\xce\xbb', 'old', 'Dropbox', 'gdrb']
>>> os.listdir(u".")
[u'someUnicodeFilename\u03bb', u'old', u'Dropbox', u'gdrb']
```

Note that the file will still open either way - it won't be represented well within Python as it'll be an 8-bit string, but it'll still work.

```
open('someUnicodeFilename\xce\xbb')
<open file 'someUnicodeFilenameλ', mode 'r' at 0x7f1b97e70660>
```

Under 3.x, as always, it's always Unicode.

Comment: What if I use something like `os.listdir()`, not creating the unicode strings myself?

Comment: I would imagine that if you have a Unicode supporting filesystem, os.listdir() will return unicode strings.

Comment: @user975135 Edited to add a note about Python 2.x and ``os.listdir()`` with Unicode.

Comment: Hm, Ok. I know this is off, but is any other encoding possible?

Comment: @user975135 *The sys.getfilesystemencoding() function returns the encoding to use on your current system, in case you want to do the encoding manually, but there’s not much reason to bother. When opening a file for reading or writing, you can usually just provide the Unicode string as the filename, and it will be automatically converted to the right encoding for you.* [Source](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-filenames)

Comment: Note that the filesystemencoding is never a UTF under Windows, so any character that's not in your locale code page will cause the non-Unicode version to fail.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
import os
import sys

for filename in os.listdir(u"/your-direcory-path/"):
  open(filename.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()), "r")
```