# OpenCV VideoCapture open file with unicode path

Tags: opencv, unicode

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017. The path/filename of a video file I'm trying to open in Unicode and VideoCapture apparently doesn't like that. Specifically, the video filename is passed in as an argument to my executable.

I would have liked to use the OpenCV CommandLineParser but that doesn't seem to support Unicode strings either.

So what's the recommended approach for handling Unicode strings passed in as an argument?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: For images you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43369056/5008845). For videos... well you'd better rename your file, or create an alias through a link

Comment: Thanks @Miki... that's the answer I was afraid of! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I did it using moviepy library which support video with unicode file path.

This is a code of reading video and show frames of each second.

```
#import libraries
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
import cv2

#read video with unicode file path.♥ is unicode and not on ascii code.
my_clip=VideoFileClip('C:/♥/video.mp4')

for t in range(0,int(my_clip.duration)):
    # it returns the frame at t second of time
    frame=my_clip.get_frame(t)
    # moviepy use RGB format while opencv use BGR format so we need to convert
    frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    #show the frame with opencv imshow.
    cv2.imshow('test',frame)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).