# What is the best way to open an image with the use of OpenCV imread function and both Unicode and ASCII path?

Tags: python, opencv, unicode, io

I've run into the problem that currently it is not possible to open Unicode path via OpenCV (4.1.1.26) in python 3.7. I'm trying to develop the best practice to do that.

When the path contains Unicode we should use something described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57872297/8668595) (u'D:\ö\handschuh.jpg' or '测试目录/test.jpg').

The first thing that I've tried to find is how to detect if a string contains Unicode. As I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4987414/8668595) - all strings in python 3 are in Unicode.

For now, I'm using such workaround:

```
   import numpy as np
   import cv2
   def read(impath, flag=-1):
    try:
        image = cv2.imread(impath, flag)
        assert image is not None, ("Image is {im} check the path {path}".format (im=image, path=impath))
    except :
        image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(impath, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        assert image is not None, ("Image is {im} check the path {path}".format(im=image, path=impath))

    return image
```

That is obviously not the best way to do that as you should never use try\except pattern.

What are the suggestions?

Comment: typo: if its currently _not_ impossible, why bother fixing it. Why should using try/except never be used? It is perfectly fine.

Comment: @PatrickArtner. Ok, thank you! As I know, it is not very good to use try\except as you may miss some exceptions during code execution.

Comment: Well, the way that you are using it is wrong, because you don't specify any exception type but instead catch all of them, but using exception handling isn't per se wrong. That said, your question is lacking, what for example is `np`? In any case, why try the first method (which may fail) at all?

Comment: Oh, one more thing: You write that you tried to find out whether a string contains Unicode and that all strings in Python 3 do. What do you think "Unicode" is and how would you recognize it in a string? I think this may be one source of your misunderstanding.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, ok, thank you! 
How to specify it? I also added some examples of Unicode (u'D:\ö\handschuh.jpg' or '测试目录/test.jpg').