# OpenCV Python can't read image from external HDD with white spaces in path

Tags: python, opencv, unicode

**EDIT 2:**
Turns out the problem was that the path had Unicode symbols so the solution is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185605/how-do-i-read-an-image-from-a-path-with-unicode-characters)

**EDIT 1:**
Meanwhile, I found out that the problem is the combination of OpenCV + Spaces in Path + External Disk. Removing ANY of the elements solves the issue so the current target is just trying to find a solution for this combination.
OS is Windows

**Problem:**
I can't load images from my **external HDD** using **Python-OpenCV**.
I can use all the `os`and `open` Python functions such as read `.TXT` files and `list`/`walk` directories from the HDD but when I try to load images using `cv2.imread` I get a `None` object...
The file path is written in a Python-friendly way (using "\" instead of "") and it works for reading the image as a binary with `open(path, "rb")`

**Already Tried:**

- r string `r"TEXT"`
- Changing `\\` to `/`
- Double quotes `"\"TEXT\"\"`
- `os` module `os.path.normpath(PATH)` and `os.path.join([HALF, HALF])`

I also read the OpenCV documentation and tried Google and StackOverflow but I don't find anyone with my problem so I'm kind of lost about what to try next...

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("G:\\Fotografias e Vídeos\\[...]\\11009982_1254240047936434_1963406974405452579_n.jpg")
print(image)
cv2.imshow("d", image)
# Output
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[NAME]\Documents\Python\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("d", image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Comment: What was your exact read command? Did you include the volume in the path?

Comment: `image = cv2.imread("G:\Fotografias e Vídeos\...\Fotografia")`

Comment: I am not a Windows user, but should it not be G:\\.....

Comment: Yes, I did use it as you said but I forgot that I had meanwhile changed to try the different possibility. I double checked now and there is the whole literal text I used and its output. Thanks for your quick answers

Comment: try reading a file that does not have spaces in the name. see if that works. what are the dimensions, number of channels and datatype for the file you are trying to read? Can you move the same file to your local disk and try reading it from there.

Comment: Using a path without spaces worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Paths with spaces need to be put inside double quotes. So you may be able to use them if you escape extra double quotes. Sorry, I am not a Windows user but try adding extra quotes that are escaped by ^ as: `cv2.imread("^"G:\\Fotografias e Vídeos\\Algarve\\Pedras del Rei 2015\\11009982_1254240047936434_1963406974405452579_n.jpg^"")`

Comment: oh boy what is this... NO, paths with spaces DO NOT need to be quoted, and MUST NOT be quoted, because that is an error. the whole issue here is that the path contained unicode characters, which OpenCV can't handle properly.