# filepath is correct but cv2.imread shows AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, ocr

I try to use `cv2.imread()` function to read a png file, but it keeps showing

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e703a124b05a> in <module>
      3 file = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\捕获.PNG'
      4 img = cv2.imread(file)
----> 5 img.shape

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Then I use `PIL.Image.open()` to open the same file, it works.
[image]

Comment: OpenCV's `imread` simply has problems with special characters in filenames. For example, I can't read images with umlauts (ä, ö, ü) in their filename.

Comment: And, here's the matching duplicate: [How do I read an image from a path with Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185605/how-do-i-read-an-image-from-a-path-with-unicode-characters)

Comment: @HansHirse I changed my code into r'filepath' but `cv2.imread()` still failed to open the picture (which is a screenshot). Then I use a different .png image. `cv2.imread()` worked just fine.