# how to use special character in imwrite()

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make some scraping with a players game data. The script is working just fine for common character (a-Z, etc) but give me an error on imwrite() for special character nickname:

```
    root = saveroot +"ocrdata/"+ playername + "-" + imgtype + ".png"
    cv2.imwrite(root, var)
```

when an imput on the variable player name as this enter:

```
甜 Player
```

The script return an error as this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/..../ocrdata/甜 Player-id.png'
```

any clue ?

Comment: This is for reading an image with unicode filename: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43185605/5008845 Just do the opposite (e.g. use `imencode` instead of `imdecode`)

Comment: https://jdhao.github.io/2019/09/11/opencv_unicode_image_path/#write-images-with-unicode-paths

Answer (score 0):

this worked ;)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


im_save_path = "测试目录/small_img.jpg"

is_success, im_buf_arr = cv2.imencode(".jpg", im_resize)
im_buf_arr.tofile(im_save_path)
```

---

[credits](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/09/11/opencv_unicode_image_path/#write-images-with-unicode-paths)