# "FAX注文0004.tif" does not read from opencv but "FAX0004.tif" can be readbale

Tags: python, opencv

Error while reading japanese character name file. Without japanese characters the file can be read.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

image_path = r"FAX注文0004.tif"    
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

plt.imshow(image)
plt.axis('off')  
plt.show()
```

Note: After renaming file from `FAX注文0004.tif` to `FAX0004.tif` the file is easily read.

```
Error: TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cv2.imdecode() to decode the image.this will help you.

```
image_path = "FAX注文0004.tif"
with open(image_path, 'rb') as f:
    image_bytes = f.read()
image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(image_bytes, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is connected with this question: [How do I read an image from a path with Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185605/how-do-i-read-an-image-from-a-path-with-unicode-characters)
Basically opencv have problems with reading special symbols, you need to rename your files or use other methods to read files, proposed in link below.

Comment: If you think a question is duplicative, vote to flag it as duplicate, don't add an answer with a link.